# Inresponsive terminal while executing a C program

Tags: c, input, kernighan-and-ritchie

I don't know how to handle a problem I encounter when I launch this program:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim){
    int c,i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
```

until this point it is a literal copy of the K&R textbook exercise 1-16. It stores all characters of an input in an array until a certain fixed size and makes a count of all this characters.

```
    for (i=i; c!= EOF && c!='\n'; ++i);
    if (c == '\n')
        ++i;

    return i;
}
```

This is the part I added. My problem is whenever I try to run this program if I input a string that is longer then the range of the array (if the code I wrote takes control), I just end up with a bleeping dot in the Windows command prompt (I can't input anything nor `Ctrl+Z` nor anything else).

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (i=i; c!= EOF && c!='\n'; ++i);` is an infinite loop. You are not reading any new character nor resetting value of `c`. So, if program comes to this code and `c` is not EOF nor newline, it loops forever.

You probably wanted something like

```
for (i=i; (c=getchar())!= EOF && c!='\n'; ++i);
```

or

```
while ((c=getchar())!= EOF && c!='\n') ++i;
```

Comment: Why do you still have `i=i`?

Comment: while the terminal doesn't "freeze" anymore, I now have to input `Ctrl+Z` 2 to 3 times (depending on the number of lines in the input).

Comment: Try `while (c!=EOF && c!= '\n') {c=getchar(); i++;}`

Comment: not only this worked, but it fixed a buggy behavious that I had noticed where sometimes the first line would get printed out instead of the longest (refer to K&R 1-16 for details). thanks a lot!

Comment: (now, I'll just try to understand what was happening.. )